# Opening an extjs window as a native "chrome window" in tideSDK - possible?

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2, tidesdk

I'm in the early stages of planning a webapp that also needs to be deployed as a desktop application using tideSDK. The latter I'm not yet familiar with. Hence, my question:

**Q:** In tideSDK, can an extjs (javascript created) window be opened in a native window (that could be moved to a second screen, for example)?

If so, how is that done? Any pointers or links would be helpful and greatly appreciated.

Or would several windows in tideSDK (triggered within the same application) act like independant browser instances? In this case, I assume, the whole extjs framework would have to be loaded again?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Thomas